# Finding any coprime number

Tags: math, numbers, rsa

I'm trying to implement RSA for fun but I'm stuck on the part where you have to find a co-prime number to n (which is p x q, where p and q are two large primes).

Is there any way to do this? I can't seem to find anything except the number of coprimes of a number, which I don't need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that any two uniformly sampled integers are coprime is [~60%](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativelyPrime.html).

You could simply pick a random integer within the desired range and test its GCD with the original number and loop (resampling it) if they are not coprime.

Comment: That's a fair chance then. I'll do it that way! :) Thanks for the fast reply and interesting article! Will accept when I can.

Comment: *n* is given, not a random integer. By design, its factors *p* and *q* are huge, so there are few numbers that are not co-prime to *n*.

Comment: What makes you think that? If it only has two factors, there aren't going to be very many non-co-primes at all since one of the two factors would have to also be a factor of the co-prime attempt.

Comment: @AaronCronin: I think that's what he said. You guys have too many double negatives; you're confusing each other and me as well.

Answer (score 1):

We are only concerned with residues modulo *n*, so there are *n* of them. A residue is not co-prime to *n* only if it is a multiple of *p* or *q* (or both).

*p* of the residues are multiples of *q*, *q* of them are multiples of *p*, one of them (zero) is both, so there are *p*+*q*–1 residues not co-prime to *n*, so the chance of a random residue (selected from a uniform distribution) not being co-prime is exactly 1/*p*+1/*q*–1/(*pq*). Since *p* and *q* are huge in actual use (rather than classroom exercise), the chance of finding a non-co-prime number is minuscule. It would also imply you have cracked the encryption for this *n*, since any non-co-prime number other than zero allows you to easily find *p* and *q*. (Apply the Euclidean algorithm to find the greatest common divisor. It is either *p* or *q*.)

Incidentally, you should expect that this will not happen by chance in your lifetime, so there is no way to test the code path that handles accidentally finding a non-co-prime number except by artificially constructing the number to be tested or by using very small numbers for *p* and *q* (in which case the testing is deficient because it fails to exercise the arithmetic for large numbers on this code path). There is really no need to even test for this or include code to handle this situation because it is much more likely the computer will break than that this situation will arise with real (huge) *p* and *q*.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>  
 int gcd(int a,int b)  
{  
  int temp;  
  while(b!=0)  
  {  
       temp=a;  
       a=b;  
       b=temp%b;  
  }  
  return a;  
   }  
   int main()  
    {  
  int n,i,d,count;  
  count=1;  
  scanf("%d",&n);  
  for(i=2;i<n;i++)  
  {  
       d=gcd(n,i);  
       if(d==1)  
            count+=1;  
  }  
  printf("%d\n",count);  
  return 0;  
        }
```

Comment: Some explanation would improve this answer.